# MD5 hash of string with CUDA

Tags: java, cuda, md5

How to calcualate MD5 hash of string using NVIDIA CUDA and Java (JCuda) ? 
Maybe, somebody have example of code? 
Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

[Example of MD5 calc in C on CUDA](http://majuric.org/software/cudamd5/source/)

[JCuda, Java Bidnigns for CUDA](http://www.jcuda.de/)

Should be sufficient to implement it your self.